# Twilio delay call connection until dialed number is answered

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-functions

I want my Twilio number to continue to ring (without being answered by Twilio) until a number I want the call forwarded to answers.

According to the docs, the [pause](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) verb when used first in the response, delays pickup of incoming calls.

Is there a way to dial another number during this pause and connect the inbound and outbound calls only when the outbound call is answered?

In essence, I am trying to set up a simple call forward using the Twilio number. Just want to make sure everyone calling the number doesn't get charged even when the call goes unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I assume you are using [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) to forward the call. If you have made a call to a Twilio number and it has reached some TwiML (that isn't `<Reject>`) then that leg of the call, the incoming leg, has started and is using Twilio resource and will incur charges regardless of whatever else happens.

Just as a technical point though, if you use the [`<Dial>` attribute `answerOnBridge="true"`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-answer-on-bridge) (and `<Dial>` is the first TwiML verb) the ringing behaviour of the call will be preserved until the other end picks up.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks answerOnBridge attribute is exactly what I was looking for.